How do I use Excel to populate value into multiple cells and color code based on options?
Screenshot of Excel Project:

I am developing a spreadsheet to perform the following functions:
-Populate the # value into the corresponding column options and color code it based on whether it's option 1 or option 2.
-Automatically move the # value to the correct columns if a person's options change.
-Use SumByColor to calculate the total per option under each Option Type
-Only the cells populated with data will be color coded by their option number
My Excel-fu is at a White-belt level and I have googled as much as I can to try and figure this out.
Using the IF formula statement, I was able to at least have the numbers move automatically to the right column if the person changes their option, but cannot figure out how to color code it so I can use the SumByColor VBA macro.
For Cell E5: (Ham being first option will be Green)
=IF($B5="Ham", $D5, IF($C5="Ham", $D5, ""))
For Cell F5: (If either Option 1 or 2 is changed to Turkey, then the value of D5 will be moved to F5 and color code to match Option 1 or Option 2)
=IF($B5="Turkey", $D5, IF($C5="Turkey", $D5, ""))
For Cell G5: (Duck is the second option and will be Yellow)
=IF($B5="Duck", $D5, IF($C5="Duck", $D5, ""))
I have used Google and AI to search for a solution. Everything keeps pointing towards VBA macro or Conditional Formatting.
I've tried Conditional Formatting and tested VBA macros that SMEs have provided for similar problems, but neither have the desired results.

A more dynamic formula (starting in cell E5):
=IF($B5=E$1,$D5,IF($C5=E$1,$D5,""))

Drag down and to the right.
Now to colour code the cells, you need 2 conditional formatting rules:

Select the entire range of data (E5:I9), with cell E5 active
Add a new rule, using formulas
Rule 1: =$B5=E$1;
Change the cell layout to desired result (change background to green);
Rule 2: =$C5=E$1;
Change the cell layout to desired result (change background to yellow);



To sum up your choices, using formula:
In E2: =SUMIFS(E5:E9,$B$5:$B$9,E$1), drag right;
In E3: =SUMIFS(E5:E9,$C$5:$C$9,E$1), drag right;


Thank you very much. This met every criteria I was trying to accomplish!
